# HTML5 Video player issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I am embedding `html5 video player` in my aspx page. Playback is OK in all browsers except chrome (Version 28.0.1500.52). Video stops automatically after 10 secs of playback (video not running completely). Its quite annoying issue. Its working fine on my college computer running chrome version (Version 29.0.1547.66).

here is html

```
<video id="intro_vid" controls width="800" height="500">
    <source src="Video/Dd.ogv" type='video/ogg;' />
    <source src="Video/Dd.webm" type='video/webm' >
    <source src="Video/Dd.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <p>Video is not visible in your browser, Please upgrade your browser</p>
</video>
```

js to show hide video player.

```
$(".vid_desi").click(function () {
    $(".introVid").lightbox_me({
        centered: true,
        modalCSS: { left: 50, top: 0 }
    });
    $(".close_Vid_btn").show();
});

$(".close_Vid_btn").click(function () {

    //alert('video close');
    $("video").each(function () {
        $(this).get(0).pause();
    });
    $(".close_Vid_btn").hide();
    $('.js_lb_overlay').hide();
    $(".vid_desi").hide();
    $(".introVid").hide();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Can u also add a fiddle demo so we can test this? It could be a bug with a particular version of Chrome. Have you reported this to google?

Comment: i have added a screenshot and will add a fiddle later. i have reported to Google as well.

Comment: Did you try this with different videos? or is it one specific video?

Also chrome has an auto-update, but that doesn't make it ok to assumme everyone has the newest version because that isn't true!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered bugs with chrome and my own html5 video players before. an update solved the issue, I logged a bug report with google and forgot about it. I wouldn't worry about it, most likely a bug with that version of chrome

Answer (score 1):

It is very common for browsers (not only chrome) to have issues or bugs with playing from HTML5 video players. Try uploading to the latest version of chrome, Version 33.0.1750.152.

The video will probably play without breaking abruptly. Otherwise, file a bug report with Google about the issue. Hopefully, it'll be rectified soon.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug in chrome 27 and 28 versions, upgrade the browser to latest version. Check this link
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224179